# Only admins get results on exposed filters

Tags: 7, users, views

When I enter a word into the exposed filter as an admin I get the results I'm looking for, but when I type the same word in as an authenticated or anonymous user I get no results at all.

**UPDATE**: Exposed filters on ALL views are not working unless user is admin.

This is my view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'search_page_aug';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'test search';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test search';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'access user profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: User: **FREE** Your Secondary Business Category (field_free_business_tag) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_free_business_tag_tid']['id'] = 'field_free_business_tag_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_free_business_tag_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_free_business_tag';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_free_business_tag_tid']['field'] = 'field_free_business_tag_tid';
/* Relationship: User: Business Tags (up to 10) (field_business_super_tags) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_business_super_tags_tid']['id'] = 'field_business_super_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_business_super_tags_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_business_super_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_business_super_tags_tid']['field'] = 'field_business_super_tags_tid';
/* Relationship: User: Business Tags (up to 5) (field_business_tags) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_business_tags_tid']['id'] = 'field_business_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_business_tags_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_business_tags';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_business_tags_tid']['field'] = 'field_business_tags_tid';
/* Relationship: User: Municipality (field_municipality) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_municipality_tid']['id'] = 'field_municipality_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_municipality_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_municipality';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_municipality_tid']['field'] = 'field_municipality_tid';
/* Relationship: User: Your Primary Business Category (field_bus_type) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_bus_type_tid']['id'] = 'field_bus_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_bus_type_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_bus_type';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_bus_type_tid']['field'] = 'field_bus_type_tid';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['id'] = 'name_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['relationship'] = 'field_free_business_tag_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['id'] = 'name_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['relationship'] = 'field_business_super_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_2']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['id'] = 'name_3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['relationship'] = 'field_business_tags_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_3']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['id'] = 'name_4';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['relationship'] = 'field_municipality_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_4']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['id'] = 'name_5';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['relationship'] = 'field_bus_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_5']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Global: Combine fields filter */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['id'] = 'combine';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['field'] = 'combine';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'combine_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['label'] = 'Combine fields filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['operator'] = 'combine_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['identifier'] = 'combine';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['fields'] = array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'name_1' => 'name_1',
  'name_2' => 'name_2',
  'name_3' => 'name_3',
  'name_4' => 'name_4',
  'name_5' => 'name_5',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'test-search';
```

Any idea what the issue could be?  Users of all roles should be able to get results.

Comment: Some questions (best to answer in your question instead of in comments). For non-admin users, do they see results when not using exposed filters? Do you have any errors in your apachelogs or drupal watchdog log when a non-admin user tries to use the filters? Are you using the latest versions of drupal core and views? If you remove the combine fields part of your view does the same problem still happen? When you say all views, I assume you mean all base tables, not just user views? Do you have any other problems on your site where users aren't able to see content they should be able to see?

Comment: @rooby I will test that this weekend and report back.